# Change text between two $ symbols

Tags: normal-mode, custom-text-object

If there is some text between quotations, such as

`"x = 5"`

I can type `ci"` in normal mode to delete the text inside the quotations and switch to insert mode.

I often want to perform this same action on text between two dollar signs, such as

`$x = 5$`

But typing `ci$` has no effect. Is there a way to configure vim for treating dollar signs like quotations?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want only `$` to be a text object, then do the following

```
xnoremap i$ :<C-u> normal! T$vt$<CR>
onoremap i$ :normal vi$<CR>
xnoremap a$ :<C-u> normal!F$vf$<CR>
onoremap a$ :normal va$<CR>
```

This will add some more text objects in your vim config.

```
for s:char in [ '_', '.', ':', ',', ';', '<bar>', '/', '<bslash>', '*', '+', '%', '$' ]
  execute 'xnoremap i' . s:char . ' :<C-u>normal! T' . s:char . 'vt' . s:char . '<CR>'
  execute 'onoremap i' . s:char . ' :normal vi' . s:char . '<CR>'
  execute 'xnoremap a' . s:char . ' :<C-u>normal! F' . s:char . 'vf' . s:char . '<CR>'
  execute 'onoremap a' . s:char . ' :normal va' . s:char . '<CR>'
endfor
```

The four commands in the for loop will add operator-pending and visual mode mappings for each of the characters in the dictionary.

Put the above commands in your vimrc for consistent behavior over all sessions.

Comment: You can remove backticks: iirc vim already has support for them as text objects

Answer (score 1):

If you do not mind installing a plugin, you have several options you can choose from

1. [vim-textobj-latex](https://github.com/rbonvall/vim-textobj-latex) (depends on [vim-textobj-user](https://github.com/kana/vim-textobj-user)) defines `i$` and `a$`
2. [vim-latex-objects](https://github.com/gibiansky/vim-latex-objects) defines `im` and `am`
3. [vimtex](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex) defines `i$` and `a$`
4. [vim-sandwich](https://github.com/machakann/vim-sandwich) defines `ib` and `ab` by default. However, vim-sandwich can easily be customized to provide `i$` and `a$`. Add following to `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/tex.vim`:

   ```
   silent! omap <unique> i$ <Plug>(textobj-sandwich-query-i)$
   silent! xmap <unique> i$ <Plug>(textobj-sandwich-query-i)$
   silent! omap <unique> a$ <Plug>(textobj-sandwich-query-a)$
   silent! xmap <unique> a$ <Plug>(textobj-sandwich-query-a)$
   ```

Note, the classic plugin [vim-latex](http://vim-latex.sf.net) ([github](https://github.com/vim-latex/vim-latex)) (aka *latex-suite*) does not provide this text object.